# How to use principal component analysis (PCA) to speed up detection?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, pca, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction

I am not sure whether I am applying PCA correctly or not!  I have p features and n observations (instances). I put these in an nxp matrix X. I perform mean normalization and I get the normalized matrix B. I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the pxp covariance matrix C=(1/(n-1))B*.B where * denotes the conjugate transpose.

The eigenvectors corresponding to the descendingly ordered eigenvalues are in a pxp matrix E. Let's say I want to reduce the number of attributes from p to k. I use the equation X_new=B.E_reduced where E_reduced is produced by choosing the first k columns of E. Here are my questions:

1) Should it be X_new=B.E_reduced or X_new=X.E_reduced?

2) Should I repeat the above calculations in the testing phase? If testing phase is similar to training phase, then no speed-up is gained because I have to calculate all the p features for each instance in the testing phase and PCA makes the algorithm slower because of eigenvector calculation overhead.

3) After applying PCA, I noticed that the accuracy decreased. Is this related to the number k (I set k=p/2) or the fact that I am using linear PCA instead of kernel PCA? What is the best way to choose the number k? I read that I can find the ratio of summation of k eigenvalues over the summation of all eigenvalues and make a decision based on this ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You apply the multiplication to the centered data usually, so your projected data is also centered.

**Never re-run PCA during testing**. Only usenit on training data, and *keep the shift vector and projection matrix*. You need to apply *exactly* the same projection as during training, not recompute a new projection.

Decreased performance can have many reasons. E.g. did you also apply scaling using the roots of the eigenvalues? And what method did you use the first place?

Comment: The projection matrix is matrix B, am I right? What is the shift vector? So, I get a 1xp vector y for a test instance. How do I project the vector y? I didn't use scaling by roots of eigenvalues, could you please elaborate on that? By method, do you mean the classification method?

Comment: Usually, one would construct the projection matrix differently, incorporating scaling factors. The shift offset is the vector used for centering, so you have B(x-mu) as projection operation.